# Update/insert only a column of database table

Tags: plugin-development, database

In the WordPress table named wp_fes_vendors, there is a total of 12 columns.

Out of these 12 columns, I want to only update the data of column named **requests**

The data i am getting for this column is from a custom form in backend stored in `$_POST['getval']`

Here is the code i tried

```
 if (!empty(isset($_POST['getval'])))
    {       
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'fes_vendors';

            $data_array = array(

            'requests' => $_POST['getval']
        

            );

            $data_where = array('requests' => $_POST['getval']);

            $wpdb->update($table_name,$data_array,$data_where);
      
          
    }
```

Html

```
<form id="myForm" name="myform" action="" method="POST" style="padding:20px;">
  <label> Select if this Vendor wishes to receive customer requests or not: </label>
  <select name="getval" id="brandSel" size="1">
      <option selected="selected" disbaled value="">-- Select status --</option>
      <option value="1">Enable</option>
      <option value="0">Disable</option>
  </select>

  <?php submit_button('submit'); ?>
</form>
```

I tried several times but the data is not being saved /updated.
Here is a picture of the db

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$wpdb->where()` incorrectly.

In your code, `$data_array` and `$data_where` are going to be exactly the same, so if we assume that `$_POST['getval']` is `1`, the resulting query will be:

```
UPDATE wp_fes_vendors SET requests=1 WHERE requests=1
```

You see how that doesn't make sense? It's setting the `requests` column to `1` for all rows where `requests` is already `1`. It's a query that will never actually do anything.

The correct way to use `$wpdb->where()` is to make sure that `$data_array` contains the column names, and the new values that you want to set them to, while `$data_where` should contain columns and values to use to identify *which* row should be updated.

For example, if I want to set `requests` to `1` for the vendor with the ID of `5`, I need to do this:

```
$data_array = array(
    'requests' => 1
);

$data_where = array(
    'id' => 5
);

$wpdb->update( $table_name, $data_array, $data_where );
```

The result of that query will be:

```
UPDATE wp_fes_vendors SET requests=` WHERE id=5
```

So this means that in your form, you need to POST both the new value of the column, as well as the ID of the vendor that you need to update.